# Python tuple not populating

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I must be missing something here when I try to populate a tuple in a for loop.

```
    ...more code above...
    colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery(queryString)

#print type(colItems)
```

Is the above line needed?

```
# print the results
for item in colItems:
    logTuple = (item.SourceName, item.Type, item.TimeGenerated, item.Message)
logTuple.sort(sortByTime)
return logTuple
```

Would the above code enter those fields into a tuple?

Below is the code to sort, I haven't been able to test it yet though.

```
def sortByTime(t1, t2):
        if t1[2] < t2[2]:
            return -1
        elif t1[2] > t2[2]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ExecQuery or the structures you're using, but I do know that in your for loop you're rewriting logTuple each time the body of the loop is executed. This should do the trick:

```
logTuples = []
for item in colItems:
    logTuples.append( (item.SourceName, item.Type, item.TimeGenerated, item.Message) )
logTuples.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2)) #credit: Thomas Jung
return logTuples
```

Comment: Oh, my bad about updating your time function, it was fine the first time. Silly me. Check out Thomas Jung version to sort; it's better. I've updated my post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

What you probably meant was to add the tuple to the list (and not to set logTuple to the last created tuple in the for loop):

```
for item in colItems:
    log = (item.SourceName, item.Type, item.TimeGenerated, item.Message)
    logTuple.append(log)
```

The sorting can be done with:

```
logTuples.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Comment: But you can't append to a tuple ?

Comment: You can do `l.append((1,))`.

Comment: This is what i get then:

C:\work in progress>ntlogdata.py
<type 'instance'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work in progress\ntlogdata.py",
 line 20, in <module>
    print colItems.SourceName, colItems.Type, colItems.TimeGenerated, colItems.M
essage
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in
__getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.SourceName

C:\work in progress>

Comment: With your input data `colItems.SourceName` cannot be evaluated. The attribute `colItems.SourceName`is missing in `colItems`. You probably meant `item`.